# Rail-to-rail op amp clipping well below rails

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-clipping

I'm using a rail-to-rail op amp (LM6132) with its power rails at -5V and +5V, connected to a function generator. I expect to be able to give it a maximum signal of 10V peak-to-peak ((i.e. -5V to +5V)) without seeing much clipping, but as soon as the signal reaches about 4.9V peak-to-peak, clipping begins. Could anyone help me understand why this is?

Thanks in advance!

edit: pictures! The oscilloscope shows the measurement from the wire pointed at by the arrow, with the input signal being 5.5V peak-to-peak
[image: without the wrong label]
[image: the oscilloscope measuring from the arrow, showing clipping. Input signal has peak-to-peak amplitude of 5.5V]

Comment: What's the load? A schematic of exactly what you have showing decoupling caps, resistor network if any, and scope shots of Vin and Vout would be helpful.

Comment: What load do you have on the output? What gain configuration? What input frequency? Where's the schematic?

Comment: *I expect to be able to give it a maximum signal of 10V peak-to-peak ((i.e. -5V to +5V))* And why would you expect that ? Look at the datasheet, even with a 100 kohm load this opamp cannot bring the output exactly to the supply rails. Almost no opamp can. You will need some margin, if you want 10 Vpp then you need to supply the opamp with +/- 5.1 V or more.

Comment: But he says he gets only 5Vpp, not 10Vpp!

Comment: So no decoupling caps?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't expect to get perfectly 10Vpp, just near to it. Certainly nearer than 5Vpp I hope!

Comment: R U sure your scope is setup right... Check the rails on there too to verify the scale.

Comment: @Trevor Yeah I tried measuring it with a different scope too, still seeing the same thing

Comment: OK I give up..is it an LM6132 or an LMX321? THey are not equivelant.

Comment: Oh! I see the confusion. The default value on the schematic is LMX, which I didn't even notice (sorry; dyslexic!), but MY op amp is the LM6132.

Comment: Out of curiosity... what frequency is that signal? Scope pic is really small.

Comment: Fixed the schematic. The signal's at 1kHz.

Comment: Considering the new IC. Can you measure also the +V and -V sources? Are you sure they are working correctly?

Comment: -V is -5.4V, +V is 5V.

Comment: What is the vertical scale on the scope?

Comment: Are perhaps you using a 50-Ohm feed through terminator? That might be a cause... Even if I would not expect such abrupt clipping...

Comment: Vertical scale is 2V, so I am getting 10Vpp output, but I would expect the output to be the same as the input without any gain, no?

Comment: Can you also measure the input voltage too? Just to know if you're actually giving +/-5V

Comment: @next-hack You found the problem. The function generator was actually outputting 10Vpp, though I'm not sure I understand why. So the op amp is working correctly after all! Thanks everyone

Comment: Gah... -1 for the complete waste of everyone's time. It's OK to make a mistake. This has been one mistake after the other, invalidating every answer as soon as they come in.

Comment: Most function generators (all?) are by default set to show the voltage you'll get on a 50-Ohm matched load. Because they have a 50-Ohm output resistance, they output 2x what they are showing, because that will be halved under 50Ohm load.

Comment: lol @pipe... yup.. another PEBKAC problem.. Still.. I feel sorry for the guy... been there done that... forget to check the obvious part.

Comment: Geez, at least you learned something today: do not trust the output amplitude of the generator **unless you terminate it properly**. Yep, that's a trap for young players.

Comment: You either terminate the function generator in 50R or you set the output to "high-Z" or something similar and it will output the set voltage into a high impedance load.

Comment: Either way.. never trust the dial on the generator. Always, use your scope to adjust/fix the input amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The following considerations are valid only considering the old (unedited) question, which was referring to LMX321 and not LM6132. /EDIT

Looking at the datasheet https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/LMX321-LMX358.pdf I see that the absolute maximum value of VCC-VEE is 8V. You're giving 10. That's probably why it saturates at +/- 5.5/2 V, and it does not even go close to 10Vpp.

No smoke? :)

Comment: Is that the same one as this? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm6132.pdf
I had to remove the original link due to lack of reputation points, sorry.

Comment: Hmm..he had the TI part listed before ..... which has a much wider range.

Comment: No, because that one has, for instance, a much wider power supply range, and goes up to 24V (+/- 12)

Comment: The OP has changed the part number to LM6132, therefore my answer is no longer valid, as it refers to the original part (LMX321).

Comment: schematic still shows the LMX part though.. ME thinks he needs to verify what he actually built too.....

Comment: Now schematics has changed too.

Comment: Just correcting my oversight. Again, sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is for +5V Vcc. Increase the PSU voltage for that extra milivolt you need. It has to be clear that even if the opamp is rail to rail it doesnt mean that the output swing  will be the supply voltage and even linear to the last milivolt.

Comment: ALso missing the point. He is running the thing at 10V supply..not 5V.

Comment: @Trevor By the time I wrote an answer, the OP has changed the description almost three times.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I just added some pictures. My issue is still getting a 10V supply to have near to 10V output swing.

Comment: I saw it on the firs iteration, but it is confusing with everything using basically the same number...